# Laravel deployment with Git

Tags: git, laravel-4, web-deployment

I have a vps with ubuntu and I want to deploy my Laravel application using Git.  Laravel has some folders for the framework itself (app, bootstrap, vendor) and a folder for the public files ("public", lol) so I want to have all these framework folders outside the "www" folder of the apache server, and the contents of the "public" folder copied to "www". I've read about making a hook the copies all the pushed files to the www folder (using a checkout), but I dont want to checkout all the files to www, just the ones that are inside "public" and the rest of the pushed files (laravel files) outside.

My folder structure would be:

- myapp (pushed from my local repo)

  - Laravel framework folders
  - Laravel public folder
- www

  - contents of the public folder from laravel

How can I achieve this structure? Im using a bare repo so I can push to it, but since its "bare", I don't have a copy of the files and I can't write a post-receive hook like: empty www folder and copy all the contents of var/myapp/public to it.
Another option is to have all the files (public and nonpublic) in the www folder, so I can use the checkout method, but I read somewhere that is better to have all the app logic outside the public www folder.

Can anyone give me a hand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider creating a symlink? like /var/www/ to /git/laravel/public/

Comment: Whatever web server you are using, be it Apache or NGINX or whatever, has a DocumentRoot or Root setting where you can set it (the "www" directory) to the `public` directory, that's what it is for.  Once you've done this, everything above the `public` directory is outside the DocumentRoot.  There is no need to copy files or use symlinks.  Just change the single configuration line in your web server to serve out of the public directory.

Comment: Sajan is correct, Once upon a time i wanted to do what you are asking but then i realised there is no need because i can modify the httpd.conf file and tell apache where i want my root. Root is what was or is specified in the httpd.conf file. to be for the application i am using. Just because a directory says www doesnt mean its root. If you have a vhost setting where you have multiple domains, you can set their roots the same way. ** Unless your on a shared hosting account then its a whole other story.

Comment: This all seems over kill, just do the following: create a folder under /srv for your web application code, then deploy yours code there, now create a vhost config for apache (I assume thats what you're using) in side the sites-available folder typically found in /etc/apache2 or /etc/httpd and then symlink that config to exist in the sites-enabled folder restart apache and you're done, you rarely should eve need to edit httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

**Deploying laravel website via git**

@marcanuy 's article proved to be an excellent resource in past , but sadly the [link](http://marcanuy.com/en/articles/36-technology/18-deploying-a-laravel-website-with-git) doesn't seems to be accessible any more.

so for noobs like me, i am explaining his answer further

**1. initiate a bare git repository in your server .**

in my set up , i have git folder and website folder in my home directory . so inside the git folder, i created a new folder named website.git . and initialized a bare git repo inside

```
cd website.git
git --bare init
```

**2. add a remote to your git, say website**

the local git repo now have a remote pointing to the repo in server.

```
 git remote add website ssh://<user>@hostname/home/<username>/git/website.git
```

**3. set up post hook script ( from @marcanuy answer )**

update working tree path . in my case /home/username/website . make post-update executable as well.

**4. point apache to your laravel public folder**

now you can push to remote website , and make changes to live site with out fuzz .

Answer (score 0):

In your bare repo edit the hook script /path/website.git/hooks/post-update with:

```
#!/bin/sh
work_tree=/website/code/path/mycoolsite
GIT_WORK_TREE=$work_tree git checkout -f
cd $work_tree
composer install
```

And make sure this script is executable. Each time you push from your local repo this script will copy your files to the dir you have chosen and install any new dependencies from your composer.json file.

Then you can make a symbolic link in your webserver root

```
 ln -s /website/code/path/site/public/ /var/www/mycoolsite
```

Or edit your apache config file to set the public folder as the new DocumentRoot.

I've wrote an article about it in [deploying a laravel website with git](http://marcanuy.com/en/articles/36-technology/18-deploying-a-laravel-website-with-git)